# Mock/stub Arguments.createMap during testing

Tags: java, android, react-native, bundle

In the React Native library theres a class https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/Arguments.java that is used for Bundles. I'm using PowerMockito to mock the Arguments.createMap() method and return an object with the following snippet:

```
PowerMockito.when(Arguments.createMap()).thenAnswer(
            new Answer<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    return new JavaOnlyMap();
                }
            });
```

The method I'm testing errors with the following message when the test is ran:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no reactnativejni in java.library.path
```

when executing this line:

```
WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Don't mock what you don't own](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don't-mock-what-you-don't-own).

Comment: as a rule of thumb yes, in this instance I need to

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Can you add your _pom.xml_ dependencies or the JARs you are using?

Comment: I think this is not possible. Arguments.createMap() in turn calls ReactBridge.staticInit which calls SoLoader.loadLibrary("reactnativejni");

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `Answer<Object>` to a variable. Mockito doesnt like it when you use the `new` operator as a parameter.

**Try something like this:**

```
Answer<Object> answer = new Answer<Object>() {
  @Override
  public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    return new JavaOnlyMap();
  }
}

PowerMockito.when(Arguments.createMap()).thenAnswer(answer);
```